# how to use python re.split to split string but keep digits?

Tags: python, string, split, digits

I'm a python learner. I want to use python re.split() to split a string into individual characters, but I don't want to split digits.

```
Example: s = "100,[+split"
The result should be ["100", ",", "[", "+", "s", "p", "l", "i", "t"]
```

I tried to use `re.split(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', s)` and `re.findall(r'[0-9]+]|\d+', s)`, but I'm really not good at using those methods. Can someone help me? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "100,[+split" 
new_s = re.findall('\d+|[a-zA-Z\W]', s)
```

Output:

```
['100', ',', '[', '+', 's', 'p', 'l', 'i', 't']
```

Comment: Thank you Ajax1234! So it should use findall rather than split. A new skill for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
[re.search('\d*', s).group()] + [val for val in s if not val.isdigit()]
```

This gets you the desired output for this particular string, but without knowing more about what types of string you are expecting it is hard to say if it will work in all cases.

This works by searching the string for numbers, and then adding to that a list of all the characters that are not numbers.

Output is:

```
 ['100', ',', '[', '+', 's', 'p', 'l', 'i', 't']
```

Comment: emmmm...yes I have seen your solution is concatenate digits with non-digits. But I'm a little confused with the [re.search('\d*', s).group()], it seems it only find out the first digit. Suppose now our s="100,[+spli25t3", the result is still the same as our previous output. Also if we successfully find several digits, maybe the concatenate method '+' will change the sequence of all the characters.